# How to Optimize query execution speed in Informix 12.10

Tags: query-optimization, informix, execution-time

[image]

One of my Informix queries for a particular view takes more than 12 minutes to run on the server pc (Windows Server 2019 with 32GB RAM). But the same query with the same amount of data is run within 1 minute in my local machine (Windows 10 with 8 GB of RAM).

So what are the possible causes of this difference?
How can I optimize runtime in my server system?

Comment: Talk about an open-ended question!  Indexes; storage organization; software versions; updated statistics; other activity on the machine; DNS lookup times; differences in client-server organization — all of these and more could be factors.  Are the query plans (from SET EXPLAIN output) the same?

Comment: Yes, the SET Explain output also takes the same time as the regular request.Above I added the result screen capture.

Comment: [Please do not post images of text in questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).  Please read the [tag:sql] tag information on [How to ask an SQL question?](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).  For this question, that means the view definition, the outline schemas of the tables used in the view, the sizes of those tables (number of rows, and the row size if the table schema is incomplete).  The SET EXPLAIN output file could be useful too — especially if the outputs are significantly different on the 2 machines.

Comment: I would also try and get SQLTRACE output for both queries as well.  While set explain would show if they are taking the same plan or not, SQLTRACE shows how much time is spent waiting for IO, which could be different if there's BUFFERPOOL configuration differences or different working happening on both machines that is affecting how much data is able to be cached in the BUFFERPOOL on 1 machine vs the other.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. one of my client system using the primary database in an extensive way. Therefore, I have reconfigured my client system.Now its working fine